# How to add a section with stats after process csv file

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am doing an experiment with Shiny to upload a csv file, process it and show two different things: 1) A summary analysis of the data, and 2) A list of values that follows some specific conditions, the code is this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(sqldf)
library(data.table)

# Define UI
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    h1("Sample Report"),
    h1(""),
    fileInput(
        'target_upload',
        'Choose file to upload',
        accept = c('text/csv',
                   'text/comma-separated-values',
                   '.csv')
    ),
    radioButtons(
        "separator",
        "Separator: ",
        choices = c(","),
        selected = ",",
        inline = TRUE
    ),
    DT::dataTableOutput("sample_table"),
    tags$style(type="text/css",
               ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
               ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
    ),
    
))

# Define server logic
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    df_products_upload <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$target_upload
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        df <-
            read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                     header = TRUE,
                     sep = input$separator)
        return(df)
    })
    
    output$sample_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
        df <- df_products_upload()
        pros <-
            sqldf('select * from df where XXXX="any value" AND XX > 2 ')
        qual <-
            sqldf('select * from df where YYYY="any value" AND XX > 2 ')
       
        AllDataIssue <-
            rbind(pros,
                  qual)

        DT::datatable(
            { AllDataIssue },
            caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
                style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
                'Table 1: ', htmltools::em('Any message.')
            ),
            extensions = 'Buttons',
            
            options = list(
                fixedColumns = TRUE,
                autoWidth = TRUE,
                ordering = TRUE,
                dom = 'Bftsp',
                filter = 'top',
                buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
            ))
    })
    
})


# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

With this code, the part 2 of my problem is solved, but I don't know how can I add a box for example that shows a `summary(AllDataIssue)` of the resulting table. I mean, I want to add an interface element that might include a basic analysis on the resulting object.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reactive that contains the filtered data, then output its summary with a renderPrint:

add this in the UI:

```
textOutput("summary"),
```

and change the server

```
AllDataIssue <- reactive({
    df <- df_products_upload()
    pros <-
        sqldf('select * from df where XXXX="any value" AND XX > 2 ')
    qual <-
        sqldf('select * from df where YYYY="any value" AND XX > 2 ')
   
    AllDataIssue <-
        rbind(pros,
              qual)
})

output$summary = renderPrint(summary(AllDataIssue())) 

output$sample_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(
        { AllDataIssue() },
        caption = htmltools::tags$caption(
            style = 'caption-side: bottom; text-align: center;',
            'Table 1: ', htmltools::em('Any message.')
        ),
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        
        options = list(
            fixedColumns = TRUE,
            autoWidth = TRUE,
            ordering = TRUE,
            dom = 'Bftsp',
            filter = 'top',
            buttons = c('csv', 'excel')
        ))
})
```

Notice the parenthesis after  AllDataIssue()`